# Android Emulator for react-native expo is not working

Tags: react-native, expo

## No address associated with host name

Having an issue when try to run my project on android emulator, there is no error in expo cli but project is not running on emulator and it gives error "Unable to resolve host 'exp.host' No address associated with host name"

Comment: Does your app requires to access the internet?

Answer (score 1):

If your app requires internet connection, and the emulator doesn't have one, then you have to enable it.

In my case, I just cold booted my emulator, and next time I ran, it worked without giving any error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, I fix it, the problem was in Mac OS wifi settings, Im just add in network > advanced settings > DNS > add 2 port, 1 = 8.8.8.8, 2 = 8.8.4.4, then reboot android simulator, and start "Cool Boot Now"